# Gateway Timeout The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server in .net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, timeout, gateway

Gateway Timeout The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server in .net application.
Will any changes require in IIS to solve the issue. This issue based on server problem

basically i uploaded more than 200 mb file using .net web application. its working good in dev server but it move to quality server it shows the gateway timeout issue

Kindly help me out to solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance,
SASIDHAR C